# SWT: ColumnWeightData and ColumnPixelData: role of the `resizable` attribute?

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have many dialogs using `TableViewer` with a `TableColumnLayout` layout.
The columns in the `TableViewers` are shown with a `TableColumnLayout` layout.
I would like to have the first column to not be resizable
I've tried all the possible combinations of `ColumnWeightData` and `ColumnPixelData`  with `resizable=false` but it does not seem to work.
Q:

- what is the `resizable` attribute used for in classes
  `ColumnWeightData` and `ColumnPixelData` ?
- how to set the first column to not be resizable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through the source code this flag doesn't seem to do anything automatically, you have to manually use its value. You do this by calling the `TableColumn` `setResizable` method.

If you are using `TableViewerColumn` it would be something like:

```java
TableViewerColumn col = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.LEAD);

ColumnLayoutData colData = new ColumnWeightData(50, false);

layout.setColumnData(col.getColumn(), colData);

// Set resizeable from column layout data
col.getColumn().setResizable(colData.resizable);
```

Comment: Thanks. Setting `resizable`to `false` directly on the `TableViewerColumn` makes the column indeed not resizable. The question about the role of the `resizable` attribute of `ColumnWeightData` and `ColumnPixelData` classes is still there. A bug? some dead code? I'm thinking about opening a bug in eclipse

Comment: Lots of code in Eclipse does what I show above. It is rather odd but seems to be how it was intended to be used.

Comment: I will look at the code and check if this can be "fixed"